# Make image fit UINavigationBar bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I got this image that I want to use in my navigation controller:

[image]

I'm setting it like this(following advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401768/iphone-setting-background-image-in-navigationbar-is-not-fitting) question):

```
UINavigationBar *theBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
if ( [theBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cabecalho.jpg"];
    [theBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

But when I run my app, I get this:

[image]

What do I do so my image can fit the navigation controller?

Thank you.

Comment: I had the same issue and basically created the image to be the same width as the navbar - is this not an option for you?

Comment: It looks that your image dimension is less than 320 the width of navigation bar, if the image is small it will repeat in the background, make sure your image width is 320 px, or, 640 px for Retina..

Comment: Just make it in 320*44 size. it will fit on navigation bar. otherwise it will not work

Comment: This image is 320x49. It should fit, right?

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar . The code you are trying will only work on >=iOS 5.0 not below.. you can subclass Navigation bar and draw the image..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution following the example of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar) question.

When I create my UINavigationController, I do this:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewLista];

if ([nav.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cabecalho.png"];
    [nav.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Comment: Your code will only work >=iOS5.0.. Its ok if you are not supporting iOS<5.0, else you need to change your code..

Comment: Right, I'm using iOS6 at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]]];
```

Refer [How to add background image on iphone Navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692487/how-to-add-background-image-on-iphone-navigation-bar) this question that may be helpful for you.

Comment: I added this code to the viewWillAppear method of the view that contains the navigation controller, but now it shows me no image at all.

Comment: Well of course you have to change the code so that it refers to *your* image.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. I found a solution and will post it here. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @iPatel, your answer helped me to solve the problem.